# php redirect method that is transparent to bot/crawler?

Tags: php, security, redirect

I would like to know how to redirect a page with php in such a way that someone crawling the site programmatically doesn't see the redirect.

I have several honey pots on my site that are getting traffic, and some false directories and files that I manually created based on reviewing the logs of other attempts. What I would like to do is to redirect someone who works their way into a blocked file or directory they should not be in i.e. wp-login.php and redirect them to one of my honey pots to record these attempts.

I looked at the php methods but not a programmer and not sure when they are crawling the site via a bot if they can 'see' the header('Location: http:// www. example. com/'); redirects I am using and thus avoid the trap.

Answer (score 1):

Crawlers see exactly the same response as a web browser does *if they send the same request*. So they can see the redirect if a browser can. However, by default a crawler/bot sends info about what it is, Google Bot tells in the request that it's Google Bot, etc. But it doesn't need to, it could just lie, telling the website it's a regular browser. Compliant bots don't usually do this, but a malicious bot could with no effort.

(This request header is btw called the User Agent, but that doesn't really matter.)

This means if your website gets a request with the user agent not associated with a browser (presumably a bot), it can generate a different response than what a browser would see. But this will never be secure as the client can just forge the user agent and you can do nothing about it.